# Admob implemenatation in XNA on WP possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna, admob

As a hobby project I have developed a simple 2D game using XNA for WP (7/8). Pubcenter has never given me an ad when testing (both on emulator and on the device), whicle I can confirm that it works because the test-mode ad works. Hence I am looking for alternatives - primarily AdMob by Google.

Unfortunately google has stopped its support for XNA since September 2013. I have tried using Adrotator to fetch ads using an AdMob ad-unit that I registered as for an IOS app - doesnt work.

Is there any way to get AdMob on XNA for WP presently ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob is currently officialy supported under WP8.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadwp

You realy should consider moving to Monogame as XNA is an abandoned engine. With monogame you can easily implement ads for variety of OSes.

Comment: The admob support for WP8 is for the xaml apps, not the ones based on XNA. Further, I am unable to create an ad-unit in my admob contol centre - there is just three options Android, Iphone, Ipad.

I havent checked out monogame, perhaps I should. I started this off as a hobby, hadnt heard of monogame back then.